# How to suppress to perform a webdynpro-method from the pre-exit

Tags: abap, webdynpro

I want to check condition in pre exit method, if that condition is false then I have to come out of the method, without calling original method.

Comment: Try to include more details and context, give a concrete scenario, tell us what you've tried so far. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Nothing can be understand from your description: what is "pre-exit" and what is webdynpro-method? WD has no methods, it is mainly a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot. However, you have some options:

1. Check the original method and see if there is a variable you can set in the pre-exit so the logic in the method is not processed;
2. Use an implicit enhancement at the top of the method you want to skip, you put the code here that you were planning to put in the pre-exit;
3. Use an overwrite-exit where you call the original method using `me->method( )` whenever you do want to call it. If I remember correctly you have to create the overwrite with the option to have access to the global vars.